# Make JavaScript bookmarklet open in new tab/window?

Tags: bookmarklet

I got a bookmarklet from Dirpy. When you're on a YouTube video, and you click it, it automatically takes you to the Dirpy website to download the video. Is there a way to make it open in a new window/tab?
I've tried a few very simple things, but I have no idea about JavaScript, so they didn't work.

Here's the script:

javascript:%20/***_Dirpy_Studio_Bookmarklet_***/(function(){var%20b=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];var%20c=new%20Date().getTime();var%20a=document.createElement("script");a.src="http://dirpy.com/js/studio-bookmarklet.js?"+c;a.onload=a.onreadystatechange=function(){if(!loaded&&(!this.readyState||this.readyState=="loaded"||this.readyState=="complete")){a.onload=a.onreadystatechange=null;b.removeChild(a)}};b.appendChild(a)})();

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The redirect to dirpy.com is done in the external script, so unless you rewrite that, no.